# Inherited control not generate code in form designer generated code

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to inherit DevExpress PictureEdit (but, I think this problem is not DevExpress specific). I add some properties to it.

```
public class RepositoryItemFotoEdit:RepositoryItemPictureEdit
{
    private Size _imageSize;
    public Size ImageSize
    { 
        get
        {
            return _imageSize;
        } 
        set 
        { 
            _imageSize = value;
            OnPropertiesChanged();
        }
    }

    [DefaultValue(InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic)]
    public new InterpolationMode PictureInterpolationMode
    {
        get { return base.PictureInterpolationMode; }
        set { base.PictureInterpolationMode = value; }
    }

    [DefaultValue(PictureSizeMode.Zoom)]
    public new PictureSizeMode SizeMode
    {
        get { return base.SizeMode; }
        set { base.SizeMode = value; }
    }        

    public RepositoryItemFotoEdit()
    {
        PictureInterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        SizeMode = PictureSizeMode.Zoom;            
    }
}



public sealed class FotoEdit : PictureEdit
{
    private FotoMenu _menu;

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_menu != null)
                _menu.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    public override Image Image
    {
        get
        {
             return base.Image;
        }
        set
        {
            if(Properties.ImageSize.Width == 0 || Properties.ImageSize.Height == 0 || value == null)
                base.Image = value;
            else
            {
                var heightProp = (double) Properties.ImageSize.Height/value.Height;
                var widthProp = (double) Properties.ImageSize.Width/value.Width;
                var prop = heightProp < widthProp ? heightProp : widthProp;

                base.Image = ImageHelper.ResizeImage(value, (int)(prop*value.Width), (int)(prop*value.Height));
            }
        }
    }

    public new RepositoryItemFotoEdit Properties
    {
        get { return base.Properties as RepositoryItemFotoEdit; }
    }

    protected override PictureMenu Menu
    {
        get { return _menu ?? (_menu = new FotoMenu(this)); }
    }

    protected override EditorClassInfo EditorClassInfo
    {
        get
        {
            var beci = base.EditorClassInfo;
            var eci = new EditorClassInfo("FotoEdit", typeof (FotoEdit), typeof (RepositoryItemFotoEdit),
                                          beci.ViewInfoType, beci.Painter, beci.DesignTimeVisible);
            return eci;
        }
    }
}
```

Property `ImageSize` appear on PropertyEditor.

[image].

But, if I change it to some value (e.g. 150; 150), it is not generate code in form designer generated code.

Note that `ImageSize` is inside `Properties` property.

```
// 
// fotoEdit1
// 
this.fotoEdit1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
this.fotoEdit1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(583, 370);
this.fotoEdit1.Name = "fotoEdit1";
this.fotoEdit1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 150);
this.fotoEdit1.TabIndex = 18;
```

That will result in `ImageSize` value revert back to 0;0. How to solve this problem?

**EDIT :**

I tried to add `[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]` to `Properties` property as sugested by someone (I forgot his name and he deleted his answer). It result to properties inside `Properties` property appear in designer generated code except those who overriden.

[image]

My designer generated code look like this:

```
        // 
        // fotoEdit1
        // 
        this.fotoEdit1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
        this.fotoEdit1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(583, 370);
        this.fotoEdit1.Name = "fotoEdit1";
        this.fotoEdit1.Properties.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(5, 2, 0, 0);
        this.fotoEdit1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 150);
        this.fotoEdit1.TabIndex = 18;
```

Note that `Properties.Padding` appear, but `Properties.ImageSize` not.

Comment: Is the latter code what you expect, or what you get? Looks fine.

Comment: @GrantThomas `this.fotoEdit1.Properties.ImageSize= new System.Drawing.Size(150, 150);` should appear in designer generated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solve the problem by add `[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]` to `Properties` property and `[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]` to `Properties.ImageSize` property.